# What are the differences between different color entries in console logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What are the differences between the magenta and aqua color log entries?

[image]

Comment: It's probably just [report banding](https://resource.microstrategy.com/Support/UploadContent/40k/TN38105_TN38105_2.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Makes it easier to distinguish separate queries.

You have eight queries there. I was able to determine that at a glance without having to drag a finger and count each one individually.

Here's the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb#L53-74). Colors are assigned on line 53, and alternate on line 72.

Colors are defined in [this file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/log_subscriber.rb#L36-L49).